# Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined in vue-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, nuxt.js

i am using jquery with nuxt js. 
there is my imported plugins

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import jn from 'vue-jquery';
import $ from 'jquery';

Vue.use(jn)
```

and this is my function

```
collect(){
        var cart = $(".coin");
        var $btn =  $(this);   
        var $coin = $('<div class="coin">')
    .insertAfter($btn)
    .css({
        "left": $btn .offset().left,
        "top": $btn .offset().top
    })
    .animate({
        "top": $cart.offset().top,
        "left": $cart.offset().left
    }, 1000, function() {
        $coin.remove();
    });
   }
```

and this is the div from where the function is being called

```
<button id="click" @click="collect()">CLICK</button>
```

now thats giving an error saying Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined
i did try this below

```
var $btn =  document.getElementById("click");
```

but then it says $btn.offset is not a function

please help me with this problem.

Comment: why do you use jQuery if you already have Nuxt?

Comment: cause i need to animate and im trying to follow this lik http://jsfiddle.net/rqwyd9c6/27/